# How can I keep updated Github repositories I downloaded from others?

Tags: bash, git, github

I have several Github repositories cloned on my computer. They are not my projects but rather other people's programs I like to use.

I usually use `git clone url` to download a repository to my computer. To keep the source code or program updated, do I need to use `git clone url` all the time for each program (and whenver I see any change in the repository)? Or is there a simpler way to keep every repository I cloned from Github updated?

I'm looking for some command like `brew upgrade` just as homebrew upgrades all the packages downloaded automatically.

Thank you very much!

Comment: `git pull` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+update+local+repository

Comment: This is very basic Git usage. Please find a Git tutorial and go through it carefully. If that doesn't do it, before asking a question, please search for existing questions. See [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the comment and sorry for the duplicate question. I did search quite a lot and read a few posts before asking this question - but since I'm a beginner I couldn't understand very well. Most questions I found were about their own Git repository so I wasn't sure if it works the same for other people's repository. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, I wanted a command or package that updates all repos and it seems like I found one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-pull-all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to run `git clone` all the time; you can actually pull each time to get changes. Better still just fork the repository and set an upstream to the  project - yours will be in sync and you will get the updates whenever the owner of the repo updates it, and the owner gets his/her reps in the number of forks.

To set an upstream to a forked repo:

- Navigate to the repository
- under the repository name click **clone or download**
- In the clone with HTTPs section, click the copy URL for the repository
- open git bash

If you type `git remote -v` and press enter you will see the current configured remote repository of your fork.

- Now type `git remote add upstream the-url-you-copied-in-the-step-above` then press enter.

That will keep your forked repository in sync with the original project

- To verify the new upstream that your project is now synced type `git remote -v` in you git bash again. 
  You will see the URL for your fork as `origin` and  the URL for the original repository as `upstream`. Meanwhile if it was a forked project you will see the URL or the original repository as `origin` and `upstream`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed instruction! I will follow your advice.

Comment: The "git bash" part is specific to (a subset of) Windows users but maybe they are the primary audience for this type of question.

Comment: @tripleee it should work with any terminal with little or no OS specific command.

Comment: Yes, but the terminal is only called "git bash" if you installed Bash via Git on Windows.

Comment: That right... Very correct thanks for pointing it out